# Update Panel Alert Comfirm Message

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, string, stringbuilder

I want to do alert comfirm message . How can I do if click Yes go on process but if click the cancel return process. Can anyone help me?

```
 System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
 sb.Append("return confirm('");
 sb.Append(message);
 sb.Append("');");


 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Message", "if(confirm('Yeterli puanınız yok. ')){alert('Yes');}else{alert('cancel');}", true);
```

Comment: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "if(confirm('Yeterli puanınız yok. ')){alert('Yes');}else{alert('cancel');}", true);`

Comment: thank you but. İf click Yes go on process but click cancel not go on process. At same time if click button always dont show this message. button click according to condition.

Answer (score 0):

the `confirm` returns **true/false** and this you need to use for your buttons to make post back or not.

Here's an example on how to make your code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button"
    OnClientClick="return confirm('sure ?');" />
```

Comment: thank you but. İf click Yes go on process but click cancel not go on process. At same time if click button always dont show this message. button click according to condition.

Comment: @AliYılmaz work with your code and find it. - I do not know what is your problem exactly because I do not have your program... so you need to work base on this answer and find it

Comment: My Problem your code I have to use this condition code behind. not button click. At the same time Update Panel using. Provided that if the condition show this validate.  if (mevcutKullaniciSepetPuan + istenilenUrunToplamPuan > mevcutKullaniciPuan)
                {
                    Button btn = sender as Button;

                    btn.OnClientClick = "return Validate();";             

                }